# Fetching machine details remotely from large group of computers

Tags: vb.net, powershell, vbscript, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to remotely collect few details (machine name, user name,MAC address, Serial number, OS version etc) from the large group of computers.
I have come up with different ways.

**Method 1:**
Deploy a script on all the machines, script will fetch the details from machine and write in to a shared excel file present in the network file share.

Challenges: 
The target environment doesn't have network share folders enabled.
Challenge in concurrent updating the excel from multiple machines at the same time.

**Method 2:**
Deploy a script on all the machines, which will run fetch the required details and send an email to particular email address with all the required details in subject line.
After all the email are received, admin can copy those emails and copy to excel, so it copies the subject line of the emails in excel rows. Later admin can delimit and seperate the column for desired report.

Challenges:
This method tried and working fine. But challenge is no.of charecters in the email subject is limitted to 256 hence can't fetch more details.

I would like to request whether anyone has any inputs or other possible methods to achieve the target.

Thank you

Comment: If you want to run the same script against multiple computers(which is clearly your case), then you can leverage PowerShell [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) cmdlet to run scripts on remote computers. You won't have to deploy scripts on all machines. You can do it on a single machine which has connectivity with the remote servers. Check out [this](https://4sysops.com/archives/use-powershell-invoke-command-to-run-scripts-on-remote-computers/) link.

Comment: Most of the information you need should be fetchable using WMI or CIM so you can fetch all the data using a single machine.